# How to upload image either .png or .jpg on ftp server in ios.?

Tags: ios, iphone, ftp

I want to upload or save image to FTP server from my iOS app. but every time I get error that **ftp not connected**

I use SCRFTPRequest library.

here is my code...

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",image]];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
NSLog(@"image saved");
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

ftpRequest = [SCRFTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://myURL"] toUploadFile:fullPath];
ftpRequest.username = @"DemoUser";
ftpRequest.password = @"DemoUser";
ftpRequest.customUploadFileName = @"inapp";
ftpRequest.delegate = self;
[ftpRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: You can use [QueueFTP](https://github.com/soulslicer/QueueFTP) for that.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi In your link there is a php link is to be specified but i cant get idea about it plz help me to salve out.

Comment: try to use White Raccoon https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon

Comment: I have no idea of `CFUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got success to upload image file on ftp server.

To upload image on ftp i used Gold Raccoon external library.with this library you can easily upload image to ftp server.

https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon

Comment: great link that is. this is really help me to get out of the big problem to save image on FTP. thanx.

Comment: @RamaniAshish does this support for background upload which means lets say the whole app goes to background mode , normally all the excution will stop except NSUrlSession , does this work ?

Answer (score 0):

From [White Raccoon](https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon),

Just Drag and Drop the `WhiteRaccoon.h` and `WhiteRaccoon.m` file and import `CFNetwork` framework in your project.

```
- (void) upload
    {

        //the upload request needs the input data to be NSData 
        //so we first convert the image to NSData
        UIImage * ourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"space.jpg"];
        NSData * ourImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ourImage, 100);


        //we create the upload request
        //we don't autorelease the object so that it will be around when the callback gets called
        //this is not a good practice, in real life development you should use a retain property to store a reference to the request
        WRRequestUpload * uploadImage = [[WRRequestUpload alloc] init];
        uploadImage.delegate = self;

        //for anonymous login just leave the username and password nil
        uploadImage.hostname = @"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        uploadImage.username = @"myuser";
        uploadImage.password = @"mypass";

        //we set our data
        uploadImage.sentData = ourImageData;

        //the path needs to be absolute to the FTP root folder.
        //full URL would be ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/space.jpg
        uploadImage.path = @"/space.jpg";

        //we start the request
        [uploadImage start];

    }

    -(void) requestCompleted:(WRRequest *) request{

        //called if 'request' is completed successfully
        NSLog(@"%@ completed!", request);

    }

    -(void) requestFailed:(WRRequest *) request{

        //called after 'request' ends in error
        //we can print the error message
        NSLog(@"%@", request.error.message);

    }

    -(BOOL) shouldOverwriteFileWithRequest:(WRRequest *)request {

        //if the file (ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/space.jpg) is already on the FTP server,the delegate is asked if the file should be overwritten 
        //'request' is the request that intended to create the file
        return YES;

    }
```

Comment: can you give me full code plz because i m new to ios.

Comment: it throws unknown error.. and delegate methods not called.

Comment: have you add the protocol in your file `WebRequestDelegate`. See my full answer

Comment: yes i add it but it throws [WRRequestListDirectory stream:handleEvent:] [Line 968] Unknown error!

Comment: and how to write url path and where assume my for this ftp://example.com/demo1/ and now i want to save image here. how to write that. what is host name and what is path./

Comment: Did you import `CFNetwork` framework in your project?

Comment: when you upload any file in FTP server, you have to provide the uploaded file name.

Comment: name is given in the path field like @"inapp.png"

Comment: i give name in uploadimage.path = @"inapp.png" but when i print it in full url it returns as "//" nothing else

Comment: Thanx for replying me and give such useful information.

Comment: Same procedure as described above

Comment: @RamaniAshish me too getting the unknown error....2014-08-01 12:35:07.755 CameraImgUpload[419:60b] -[WRRequestListDirectory stream:handleEvent:] [Line 933] Unknown error!