# uploading an image to FTP server in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

Hello everyone I'm trying to upload an image to a FTP server using an iOS app in swift.

I used the below library.
[FileProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider)

the issue Im facing that the file uploaded to the server is having zero Bytes size.

I checked the below questions, but I couldn't resolve my issue.

1. [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090952/upload-multiple-images-to-ftp-server-in-ios)
2. [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335867/upload-file-to-ftp-server-with-swift)
3. [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754571/how-to-upload-image-either-png-or-jpg-on-ftp-server-in-ios)

this is the code I wrote.

```
var ftpProvider: FTPFileProvider?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let server: URL = URL(string: "ftp://x.x.x.x/")!
    let username = "xxxxx"
    let password = "xxxxxxx"

    let credential = URLCredential(user: username, password: password, persistence: .forSession)

    ftpProvider = FTPFileProvider(baseURL: server, mode: FTPFileProvider.Mode.passive, credential: credential, cache: URLCache())

    ftpProvider!.delegate = self

}



 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else{
        print("RIZK:- issue in picking images ")
        return
    }

    // saving the image as a file fileName.png
    _ = SavingManager.shared.saveImage(image: chosenImage)

    // getting the local url of the image file
    guard let localURL = SavingManager.shared.getSavedImageURL("fileName.png") else{
        return
    }

    //just to check if the image is being returned successfully 
    guard  let imagePreview = SavingManager.shared.getSavedImage(named: "fileName.png") else{
        return
    }

    //getting the file size 
    SavingManager.shared.getFileSize(localURL.path)

    //naming the file 
    let imageName = "\(DataManager.shared.getArchivedUser()?.lastName ?? "Guest")-\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).png"

    //uploading the image 
    let progress = ftpProvider?.copyItem(localFile: localURL, to: "files/\(imageName)", overwrite: true, completionHandler: { (error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("RIZK:-- Ready to upload")
        }else{
            print("RIZK:--\(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
        }
    })

    print(progress?.fractionCompleted ?? 0)



    self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

I also added the delegate methods but the they are not being accessed at all,

please if anyone used this library provide help.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use FTP for ***anything*** that is externally facing / accessible from the internet. Anybody can intercept the password and get into your server.

*If* you want to use something *like* FTP use SFTP or FTPS.

**But** your app should use neither of these. Because I (as some user) can get your .ipa, debug / disassemble it, retrieve the hardcoded credentials from it and access your server, upload and delete whatever I like. You need to provide an API endpoint which accepts a file upload and puts the file somewhere. You must not share your ftp credentials with anything that a customer gets its hands on.